# TActorIterator initialization in c++ using unreal engine 5 and visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I am trying to loop through all StaticMeshActor in my game world to identify them by tags.

To try and solve this I have tried the following TActorIterator initializations, but all of them give the same error: Incomplete type is not allowed and Local variable is not initialized. This is the exact error message.

```
TActorIterator<AStaticMeshActor> ActorItr(GetWorld());

TActorIterator<AStaticMeshActor> ActorItr =
```

TActorIterator(GetWorld());

```
TActorIterator<AStaticMeshActor> ActorItr = TActorIterator(GetWorld());
```

What can I do to initialize ActorItr?

Update: I use the following code and includes

```
    #include "Engine/World.h"
    #include "Engine/Engine.h"
    #include "Kismet/KismetMathLibrary.h"
    #include <Engine/StaticMeshActor.h>
```

```
for (TActorIterator<AStaticMeshActor> ActorItr(GetWorld()); 
ActorItr; ++ActorItr)
```

Comment: An "incomplete type" error is often caused by having only a forward declaration but no definition (aka.: correct `#include`). although you should really be providing a [mre] including the exact error message

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by adding an include

```
#include "Engine.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "Engine/Engine.h"
```